# how can i redesign this query?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

How can i redesign the following query to avoid errors :

```
String sqlQueryToMakeTable = "create table " + UserEmail + 
                                        "(" +
                                           "NameOfThePhoto varchar(255)," + 
                                            "Caption varchar(255)" +
                                         ")";
// UserEmail is of type String
```

*UserEmail* is of the form *user@host.com* and when i execute the query i get these errors :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Lexical error at line 1, column 18.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:562)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnection.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnection.java:964)
    .....
```

I understand the reason for exception. I run this query directly by placing the email address in the double quotes but what do i do here ?

**EDIT** Can't we have @ in table name ?

[image]

Comment: why on earth do you want a table per user?!?!?

Comment: do you really need the character "@" in your table name? why not just remove this character from UserEmail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most databases permit arbitrary characters in table names as long as you enclose them in the correct quotes for the DB. For example,

For MySQL:

```
"create table `" + UserEmail + "` " +
```

For DB2:

```
"create table \"" + UserEmail + "\" " +
```

For SQL Server:

```
"create table [" + UserEmail + "] " +
```

For Derby it looks like double quotes might work, like with DB2: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj08.html

Then again, why are you creating a table for each user??

**Update**: The usual approach is having a single table of captions that also contains some data that can be used to identify the user. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE PhotoCaptions (
    UserEmail      varchar(255),
    NameOfThePhoto varchar(255),
    Caption        varchar(255)
)
```

Then, to find the caption for a particular photo of a particular user, you would use a query like this:

```
SELECT Caption FROM PhotoCaptions 
WHERE UserEmail = 'email' AND NameOfThePhoto = 'photoname'
```

Comment: The reason : When a registered user submits a photo with a caption,photo name with it's caption get's to his table,so that when there is a need to display them,i connect to the database and find the caption for the particular photo

Comment: @SuhailGupta See update for the usual way to using a relational database.

Comment: will you please list some disadvantages of having a table per user ?

Comment: There are several: the table name cannot be used as data, so you have no way of listing users that have uploaded a photo with the same name for example. Also, databases (or db management tools) may not be optimised for a large numbers of tables, so the number of tables may be limited or finding the data may become unacceptably slow.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a table name liek an email address but you can't have a `@` in your table name. Replace it.

But as arnaud stated: Are you sure you want to create a table for every user?

Beter make a general email table with a column containing the userid.

EDIT:

You can have a @ in your table name if you use backticks. Example:

```
create table `user@host.com` (id int);
```

But you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is to quote the UserEmail variable like this:

```
String sqlQueryToMakeTable = "create table \'" + UserEmail + "\'" + 
                                        "(" +
                                           "NameOfThePhoto varchar(255)," + 
                                            "Caption varchar(255)" +
                                         ")";
```

i think this will work. Table names in mysql can have both . and @ sign.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what database you are using. In sql server you need to use `[table_name]` in mysql you need `'table_name'`

This will suppress any special character meaning in the table name